# Allow Elastic IP to be reassociated if already attached

Tags: aws-cloudformation, boto3, boto

The web interface has a useful option "Allow Elastic IP to be reassociated if already attached". How to do this using cloudformation? (or boto)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to specify that for ec2-vpc-only account.

> [EC2-Classic, VPC in an EC2-VPC-only account] If the Elastic IP
>   address is already associated with a different instance, it is
>   disassociated from that instance and associated with the specified
>   instance. If you associate an Elastic IP address with an instance that
>   has an existing Elastic IP address, the existing address is
>   disassociated from the instance, but remains allocated to your
>   account.

Answer (score 2):

This option is a safeguard to prevent accidental IP reallocation through console.

You perform this action with AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation. As per documentation, if the Elastic IP address is already associated with a different instance, it is disassociated from that instance and associated with the specified instance. If you associate an Elastic IP address with an instance that has an existing Elastic IP address, the existing address is disassociated from the instance, but remains allocated to your account.

So through CF, reassociation option is the default.

For more information see [AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip-association.html)